# Simple, but this won't enter the password on a protected excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a macro to run through 150 Excel workbooks with 5 sheets in each workbook and enter the password on one particular sheet.

I have removed the other stuff that the macro does, but if I remove the password part the macro loops through all the files as it should. Which means I have to enter the passwords manually.

The password is just not accepted, leaving the sheet protected.

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Examnew()    
    Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range             'define loop names    
    Dim wbmaster As Workbook                      'name for master workbook    
    Dim wbtarget As Workbook                      'name for student workbook    
    Set wbmaster = ActiveWorkbook                 'set the name for the master

    'Student numbers in cells B3:B64 WARNING SET TO 2 STUDENTS ONLY FOR TEST
    'NOTE that st Nums are in col B with a duplicate in col A to collect results.

    Set rRng = wbmaster.Sheets("studentlist").Range("B3:B4”)

    For Each rCell In rRng '<                | loop through "students" range
        '<                                     | now open Student exam workbook and set to name "wbtarget"
        Workbooks.Open ("/Users/tester/Final_V1/" & rCell.Value & ".xlsx")

        Set wbtarget = Workbooks(rCell.Value & ".xlsx")
        Sheets("ANSWERS").Unprotect "Coursework2019"

        'Other stuff normally here…   
        wbtarget.Close (True) '<            | now save and close the student file...

    Next rCell   '<                          | next student number
End Sub
```

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `wbtarget.Sheets("ANSWERS").Unprotect "Coursework2019"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are some wrong parenthesis in your code.

   Parenthesis for parameters are necessary if the function should return a result. If a procedure/function does not return a result parenthesis are **not allowed**!

   See this examples:

   ```
   SomeProcedure(Parameter)         'wrong
   SomeProcedure Parameter          'correct

   result = SomeFunction(Parameter) 'correct
   result = SomeFunction Parameter  'wrong
   ```
2. You must specify in which workbook your `Sheets("ANSWERS")` is: `wbtarget.Sheets("ANSWERS")`

So it should be something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Examnew()    
    Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range             'define loop names    
    Dim wbmaster As Workbook                      'name for master workbook    
    Dim wbtarget As Workbook                      'name for student workbook    
    Set wbmaster = ActiveWorkbook                 'set the name for the master

    'Student numbers in cells B3:B64 WARNING SET TO 2 STUDENTS ONLY FOR TEST
    'NOTE that st Nums are in col B with a duplicate in col A to collect results.

    Set rRng = wbmaster.Sheets("studentlist").Range("B3:B4")

    For Each rCell In rRng 
        Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open("/Users/tester/Final_V1/" & rCell.Value & ".xlsx") 
        '^ set the open workbook directly to the variable

        wbtarget.Sheets("ANSWERS").Unprotect Password:="Coursework2019"
        '^ you must specify the workbook here!!!

        'Other stuff normally here…   
        wbtarget.Close SaveChanges:=True 'submit parameters without parenthesis!
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: `SomeProcedure(Parameter)         'wrong` If there is only one parameter, it is a valid syntax to force Parameter to be passed ByVal instead of ByRef.

Comment: @VincentG wow didn't know that. Thanks for clarification. It even works if parameter is explicitly declared `ByRef` like `SomeProcedure(ByRef Parameter)`. That is still very confusing I think, because these parenthesis are different ones from the others (in their behavior) it works because it is the same as in `SomeProcedure (Parameter1), (Parameter2)` vs `result = SomeProcedure((Parameter1), (Parameter2))`. Most people won't recognize the extra space before the parenthesis in `SomeProcedure (Parameter)` and won't recognize that there is a completely different behavior now. Bad design of VBA.

Comment: I'll be editing this and testing later... curious that some of the removed code works when it clearly should not according to the errors I had above...

Comment: @SolarMike As Vincent pointed out it worked even with these parenthesis because you only used one parameter it wasn't a syntax error but change in behavior `ByRef -> ByVal`. So the parenthesis was syntactically correct but the behavior of the parenthesis was not what you thought it was. • Nevertheless since it doesn't make a difference if the parameter was submitted `ByVal` or `ByRef` in this special case your version didn't show up a different result. But the correct way would be as I showed in the answer. • The actual issue why your code didn't work was the missing `wbtarget.` for the sheet.

Comment: Well, included the suggestions for the password which functions fine. But setting the open workbook directly to the variable causes a "grant access" window to come up. Put back to the two separate statements and it works fine... So, thanks very much.

Comment: @SolarMike that's strange it should work in one statement. There should be no difference.

Comment: It's quite happy with the password line and the save line... Just that Open and Set combined causes that dialogue box to come up... I'll live with it "as is" as what the code does is to open a student's exam file, paste in formulae, collect grade and return the grade to a list... Which is just magic :)