# How can I unprotect a external excel file before I paste data into it using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am setting up a "Job Request form" and having a macro send that info over to a "Job Queue".  I have a macro that works perfectly if I don't have any protected sheets.  What I am having issues with is having the "Job Queue"/"target_workbook" workbook being protected.  I want to have my macro unprotect all the sheets in "target_workbook before all the information is pasted and then protect all the sheets before it closes the "Target_Workbook".  This is the current Macro I am using that works with no protections present.

```
Dim main_workbook As Workbook, target_workbook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, 
ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As String, r2 As String
Dim s0 As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
Dim next_row As Long, col_number As Integer, close_workbook As Boolean

 'CONFIG HERE

'workbook path to paste in
Set target_workbook = _
Workbooks.Open("S:\3D Print Lab_Revised\Print Lab Queue.xlsm")

'ranges r1,r2, from Active Workbook
'-------------------------------------
r1 = "A3:C3"
r2 = "A5:I17"

'-------------------------------------
s0 = "Main"   'sheet name to copy from
'-------------------------------------
s1 = "FormLab Queue"   'sheet name to paste r1
s2 = "Pro 2 Plus Queue"    'sheet name to paste r2
s3 = "Archive Jobs"    'sheet name to paste r3

col_number = 1 'column number to paste
col_date = 1
close_workbook = True 'close the target_workbook once the macro ends?
'-----------------------------
'END OF CONFIG

'turn screen updating off
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy range1 from This_workbook & get the next row of s1 in the target workbook
Target_workbook.sheets(s1).unprotect Password:="YYYY"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r1).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range1 in sheet s1 of the target_workbook

target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, col_date) = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")

'This is more code that mimics the few lines above

'Save
Target_workbook.sheets(s1).Protect Password:="YYYY"
target_workbook.Save

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'close target_workbook in the end?
If close_workbook Then
    target_workbook.Close
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: See my Q & A here, I was doing the same thing with protected sheet and password, so it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54142256/4961700  If it does give it a vote...

Comment: I believe I have been doing what was suggested in your post.  I have "Target_workbook set to the open file.  I then use ""Target_workbook.sheets(s1).unprotect Password:="YYYY". ""  When I do this, I can not paste into that sheet which to me means its is not actually unprotecting that sheet.  I also dont know where I should be putting that line of code into the rest of my Code.

Comment: Well, if you are doing what I did, then it will be working. But I don't see the password bit with your open statement at the top...

Comment: So, you know the password to unprotect the involved sheets. Is this understanding correct? If yes, when you try manually unprotecting, does it work using the password you know? Do you have the knowledge about other protection type (workbook protect structure, for instance)?

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't have it in the above code because I wanted to show how the code looked when it worked.  I didnt explain very well that I was looking at how I should implement ""Target_workbook.sheets(s1).unprotect Password:="YYYY". "" to keep the code working with the sheets being protected.

Comment: @FaneDuru I do know the password to unprotect all the sheets I need access too.  If I manually go in and unprotect the sheets inside my "Target_workbook" then this code works fine.  I don't know about the other ways to protect a workbook very well.  I am hoping to keep my "target_workbook" completely locked down outside of this macro adding data to it or the few people that know the password need to use it.

Comment: Not sure I've got you... So, you are able to unprotect all sheets using the password you know **inside my "Target_workbook"**. What do you mean by that? Do you try unprotecting the sheets without opening the workbook? I am not talking about the existing code. In this moment this aspect is irrelevant... Then, what code do you use to unprotect sheets and where did you place the code lines doing that?

Comment: @FaneDuru If I open the file that is set to my "target_workbook" manually  and remove the sheet protections and save it in that state, then my marco in the activeworkbook (the one I am trying to copy data out of) works just fine.  It only breaks when my "target_workbook has sheets protected.  I went and edited my post to include the code that I am running to try and unprotect the "target_workbook".

Comment: Should I understand that only `sheets(s1)` is protected? Does the code trying to unprotect raise any error? If yes, what error and on which line?

Comment: Sheets(s2) and Sheets(s3) are also protected.  I am getting an error stating that I am trying to paste to a protected sheet.  This is the line that is highlighted in debug after I acknowledge the error.  `target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(next_row, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion, but I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I had the unprotect line correct and it was working, but I was not paying attention to what paste line it was debugging me too.  I just had to add the next sheet to unprotect further down.  I thought I kept error out on the first paste command not the second one.

Comment: Then, like I supposed, it needs unprotected of all involved cells. You should write, in fact I will post an answer with the extra necessary code lines... You must also preliminary check if the sheets are protected. Otherwise, the code will raise an error in case of other workbooks not having protected sheets. If you could handle it, it is OK. I will not post anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple functions to check workbook / worksheet protection:

```
Public Function isWorkbookProtected() As Boolean
    isWorkbookProtected = ThisWorkbook.ProtectWindows Or ThisWorkbook.ProtectStructure
End Function

Public Function isWorksheetProtected(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    isWorksheetProtected = ws.ProtectContents Or ws.ProtectDrawingObjects Or ws.ProtectScenarios
End Function
```

And here are some sub to protect / unprotected workbook / worksheet to use as you like:

```
Public Sub protectWorkbook(ByVal strPassword as String)
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:=strPassword, Structure:=True, Windows:=True
End Sub

Public Sub unprotectWorkbook(ByVal strPassword as String)
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
End Sub

Public Sub protectWorksheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal strPassword as String)
    ws.Protect Password:=strPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    ws.EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub

Public Sub protectAllWorksheets(ByVal strPassword as String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        protectWorksheet ws, strPassword
    Next ws
End Sub

Public Sub unprotectWorksheet(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal strPassword as String)
    ws.Unprotect Password:=strPassword
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I came up with that worked at unprotecting the sheets before the paste command was given.  Then protected the sheets before the workbook was closed.

```
Sub Export_To_Queue()

Dim main_workbook As Workbook, target_workbook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As String, r2 As String
Dim s0 As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
Dim next_row As Long, col_number As Integer, close_workbook As Boolean

'CONFIG HERE
'------------------------------------
'workbook path to copy from
'Set main_workbook = _
'Workbooks.Open("/Users/user/Desktop/main.xlsm")

'workbook path to paste in
Set target_workbook = _
Workbooks.Open("S:\3D Print Lab_Revised\Print Lab Queue.xlsm")

'ranges r1,r2,r3,r4,r5 from main_file
'-------------------------------------
r1 = "A3:C3"
r2 = "A5:I17"

'-------------------------------------
s0 = "Main"   'sheet name to copy from
'-------------------------------------
s1 = "FormLab Queue"   'sheet name to paste r1
s2 = "Pro 2 Plus Queue"    'sheet name to paste r2
s3 = "Archive Jobs"    'sheet name to paste r3

col_number = 1 'column number to paste
col_date = 1
close_workbook = True 'close the target_workbook once the macro ends?
'-----------------------------
'END OF CONFIG

'turn screen updating off
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'copy range1 from This_workbook & get the next row of s1 in the target workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r1).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range1 in sheet s1 of the target_workbook

target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, col_date) = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")

'copy range2 from main_workbook & get the next row of s1 in the target workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r2).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 2

'paste range2 in sheet s2 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Cells(next_row, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'copy range1 from This_workbook & get the next row of s2 in the target workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r1).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'paste range1 in sheet s2 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(next_row, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(next_row, col_date) = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")

'copy range2 from main_workbook & get the next row of s1 in the target workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s0).Range(r2).Copy
next_row = target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 2

'paste range2 in sheet s2 of the target_workbook
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Cells(next_row, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues



  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws1 = target_workbook.Worksheets("FormLab Queue")
  
  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws1.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws1.Range("A3:M1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Pro 2 Plus (FDM)"
  
  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws1.Range("A4:M1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  '3. Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    ws1.ShowAllData
    ws1.Range("A3:M1000").AutoFilter
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws2 = target_workbook.Worksheets("Pro 2 Plus Queue")
  
  
  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws2.Range("A3:M1000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Form 3 (SLA)"
  
  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws2.Range("A4:M1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  '3. Clear Filter
  On Error Resume Next
    ws2.ShowAllData
    ws2.Range("A3:M1000").AutoFilter
  On Error GoTo 0

'Save
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
target_workbook.Save

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'close target_workbook in the end?
If close_workbook Then
    target_workbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a slight type-o in the code.  Its supposed to read "Protect" in the following lines `'Save
target_workbook.Sheets(s1).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
target_workbook.Sheets(s2).Unprotect Password:="YYYY"
target_workbook.Save`  Not Unprotect.